# Questions that answer themselves without an Answer

Tags: discussion, answering-questions, answers, unanswered-questions

In [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4132/86), for example, the asker gives two answers in the body of his question in "Update:" edits, but hasn't posted either as an answer so will this question now always show as being unanswered?

In [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4391/86) the answer is posted in a comment against another answer.

How do/should we handle this kind of thing? I always feel like reposting the answer as an Answer, but never have as that seems so uncool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Answers" posted in comments are fair game to be reposted as real answers.

You can attribute the answer to the commenter, but there's no defensible reason to *not* post an answer as an answer.. we have the opposite problem (comments as answers) all the time, but that's because commenting requires 50 rep, and answering requires none.

Comment: I would hope that one would leave a @comment for the user suggesting they re-post as an answer "so it can be accepted" before writing it as an answer oneself.

Comment: In FoleyIsGood's second example the question was migrated here so the question asker doesn't have an account on Android.SE so there doesn't seem to be any way for any answers to be accepted.

Comment: And if the OP does not repost the update as an answer within, say, 48 hours, go for it. That's a personal rule of thumb. YMMV. It's about getting the answers, not leading everybody by the hand all the time...

Answer (score 9):

I'd ask the person with the answer to post it as an answer.  If they don't, I would say feel free to post it yourself; users shouldn't have to hunt through the comments to see if the answer's there instead.  Make it community wiki if you feel uncomfortable with receiving rep for the answer.